# Given $y$, find the $x$ value of a point on a Bezier curve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have linear equation of Bezier curve with one control point:

```
f[x_] := (1 – t)^2 x0 + 2 (1 – t) t x1 + t^2 x2;
f[y_] := (1 – t)^2 y0 + 2 (1 – t) t y1 + t^2 y2;
```

I have a specific Bezier curve and $y$ value and I want get the corresponding $x$ point on my curve.

I have the following second-order equations:

```
x[t_] := a t^2 + b t + c;
y[t_] := d t^2 + e t + f;
```

I solve these equations and get two values for $t$ and then replace $t1$ and $t2$ in $y$ linear equation of the curve and if answer of each one equal to my input $y$.  Then I replace that $t$ in $y$ linear equation of the curve and get my $x$.  My problem is that sometime answer of none of $y$ linear equation of the curve is not equal to input $y$.
for example I have these values

```
x0:=1
y0:=30
x1:=20
y1:=1
x2:=50
y2=30
```

and I want $x$ for

```
y:=10
```

I try my method for some curves and I find out when $delta$ is negetive in above second-order equation it dont work right.

I don't know what is my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: Do you really mean to raise to the power of `2P0` (as your code states)?  And what can the code snippet `[x, y]` possibly mean?  And instead of `x(t)` to you actually mean `x[t_]`?  And do you want to raise the value `at` to the second power (as your code states)?  I think you have many many syntactic errors here.

Comment: you should give a specific example.

Comment: @george2079 I edited my question

Answer (score 2):

I hope I have understood your question correctly.

The problem is that your Bezier curve (blue) does *not* intersect with the line $y=10$ (red) as you can see from the following plot.

```
fx[t_] := (1 - t)^2 x0 + (1 - t) t x1 + t^2 x2;
fy[t_] := (1 - t)^2 y0 + (1 - t) t y1 + t^2 y2;
{x0, y1} = {1, 30};
{x1, y1} = {20, 1};
{x2, y2} = {50, 30};
y = 10;
Show[{
  ParametricPlot[{fx[t], fy[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All],
  ParametricPlot[{t, y}, {t, 1, 50}, PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

[image]

(note that the horizontal axis does not correspond to $y$=0).

However, for a different value of `y` you can get a solution as follows.

```
y = 20;
t = t /. Solve[fy[t] == y, t]
```

[image]

The variable `t` now contains two parameter values for which `fy` is equal to `y`; more precisely, `fy[ t[[1]] ]` is now equal to `y` and `fy[ t[[2]] ]` as well. The intersections are now easy to obtain:

```
intersection1 = {N[fx[ t[[1]] ] ], fy[ t[[1]] ]}
```

[image]

```
intersection2 = {N[fx[ t[[2]] ] ], fy[ t[[2]] ]}
```

[image]

Finally, you can now plot everything:

```
Show[{
  ParametricPlot[{fx[t], fy[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All],
  ParametricPlot[{t, y}, {t, 1, 50}, PlotStyle -> Green],
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Magenta, Point[intersection1]}],
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Orange, Point[intersection2]}]}]
```

[image]